# export data from oracle 10g and import to oracle 9i

Tags: database, import, oracle10g, export

HI all
Can you tell how to import data from oracle 10g to Oracle 9i.  Is it ok i can export the data from Oracle 10g and import it to 9i directly, it should work??? or i need to follow some other procedure???

Kindly help me
Thanks in advance
Joseph

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exp and Imp are the best way to go for a single data move. I would second the suggestion of database links if you need to have continuous access to the data.

One problem is the files produced by imp and exp are not backwardly compatible. That is if you use the 10g version of exp to create a dump file, you can't use the 9i version of imp to import the data.

In  this case you need to use the 9i version of exp, connected to the 10g database, then use the 9i version of imp to import the data.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do the export using the usual exp / imp commands to perform the transfer.

http://wiki.oracle.com/page/Oracle+export+and+import

Comment: Thanks Buddy, il check the details

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a database link between the databases. exp / imp is faster but a database link makes it possible to do continuous export / import.

Comment: Thanks Buddy, il check your suggetion